# Firebase functions emulators with onRequest not working locally with android emulator

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

1. Run functions locally with a `functions
   .region(region)
   .https.onRequest(identify);` endpoint
2. Use firebase emulators in android app:

   ```
   private fun useFirebaseEmulators() {
   // 10.0.2.2 is the special IP address to connect to the 'localhost' of
   // the host computer from an Android emulator.
   val settings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
       .setHost("10.0.2.2:8080")
       .setSslEnabled(false)
       .setPersistenceEnabled(false)
       .build()

   val firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
   firestore.firestoreSettings = settings

   FirebaseFunctions.getInstance().useFunctionsEmulator("http://10.0.2.2:5001");
   ```

   }
3. Start android emulator, call the endpoint from step 1. in emulators
4. Firebase functions are not called

Comment: Are you able to share further information? Logs specific to the time-frame in which the call was made would be helpful.

Comment: Not now, I have moved away from Firebase emulators on Android until its more mature.